# Quiz based recommendation system

Tags: machine-learning, python, recommender-system

For my project I would like to make a 'quiz' based recommendation system (for books for example). If a new user comes to the website I want to find out his taste based on some questions, in which I ask him, for example, to select his most preferred genre out of list of options, then his education level, age, etc... Based on the selection it would recommend top 5 books, for example. I was wondering if there are any tutorials for a system like that or how should I go about this (I have been trying to find one but did not manage). Any advice is appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you would want something like a decision tree. There are few ways to build decision trees but it really depends on the level of complexity you are willing to build to. The catch is you need a lot of data on some sample population to build any of these. Do you have such data?

Comment: Actually an amendment - there is one you can build without data and just use your own knowledge to construct. They are called Bayesian Networks (a.k.a. Bayesian Belief Networks) and they can be built without any coding.